# Getting "Cannot read property 'value' of null" in page 1 for an id in page 3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this static website where I have 3 pages. And all of the pages have a single Javascript file.

Page 3 contains a canvas with an id of `canvas`. So now when I try to go to page 1, the website breaks with an error in the console that says:

`Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`.

Page 1 doesn't have any canvas element. What could be done in this situation?

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

JS

```
const canvas                    = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx                       = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check if the canvas constant is null before accessing it.

```
if (canvas) {
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // do stuff
}
```

If you're using es6 you can do [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like so

```
const ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d'); // returns undefined if canvas is null
```

Be aware that not all browsers support es6 - if you need to support older browsers you could compile your script with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or something alike.

Comment: is Optional Chaining supported in all browsers?

Comment: Nope only newer once - see edited answer and [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining)